# How to create an new column on a DF2 using two DF1 columns as requisite

Tags: pandas, dataframe, compare, filtering

I have two dataframes with different data and I need to add a new column on DF2 based on information obtained in two columns of DF1. In the example below, I need to check all entries that have the same city AND DOB value in both DF and add a new column in DF1 saying YES or NO.

```
DF1:
City      DOB        Gender      Test
NYC   01/05/1990       F        Positive
NYC   01/06/1991       M        Negative
LA    12/01/1980       F        Negative
BOS   11/11/1987       M        Positive

DF2:
City      DOB        Gender
NYC   01/05/1990       F        
NYC   04/22/1980       M        
LA    12/01/1980       F        
BOS   07/18/1984       M
```

So my output would be:

```
DF1'
City      DOB        Gender      Test        New_column
NYC   01/05/1990       F        Positive        YES
NYC   01/06/1991       M        Negative        NO
LA    12/01/1980       F        Negative        YES
BOS   11/11/1987       M        Positive        NO
```

The closest I got was using the code below, however it only search in one of the DF1 columns and not in the other (in my case, It adds the value YES in all entries that has the same DOB).

```
df1.loc[(df1.City.isin(df2.City))&(df1.DOB.isin(df2.DOB)), 'New_column'] = "YES"
```

Is there any way to do it with pandas? I have a really large dataset and this code will save me some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where`

```
import numpy as np

rule = (df1["City"] == df2["City"]) & (df1["DOB"] == df2["DOB"])
df1["new_column"] = np.where(rule, "YES", "NO")

print(df1)
  City         DOB Gender      Test new_column
0  NYC  01/05/1990      F  Positive        YES
1  NYC  01/06/1991      M  Negative         NO
2   LA  12/01/1980      F  Negative        YES
3  BOS  11/11/1987      M  Positive         NO
```

Comment: Think you should have the `Test` information in the output as well

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that OP altered df1 in their output, not df2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how large the data is, or limitations around that and a solution using something like the following:

```py
df3 = (
    df2.set_index(["City", "DOB"])
    .join(
        df1.set_index(["City", "DOB"])
        .drop("Gender", axis="columns")
        .assign(
            new_column=list(
                itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(["yes", "no"]), df1.shape[0])
            )
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
)
```

Which outputs:

```
  City         DOB Gender      Test new_column
0  NYC  01/05/1990      F  Positive        yes
1  NYC  04/22/1980      M       NaN        NaN
2   LA  12/01/1980      F  Negative        yes
3  BOS  07/18/1984      M       NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have some fun and compare a subset of the dataframe of those two columns directly and take the sum of the `boolean` values with a condition if it equals 2. Then, replace the booleans with `Yes` or `No`. This approach assumes the values are in the same order and same length.

```
DF1['New_column'] = ((DF1[['City', 'DOB']] == DF2[['City', 'DOB']]).sum(axis=1) == 2).replace([True,False], ['YES', 'NO'])

    City        DOB Gender      Test    New_column
0   NYC  01/05/1990      F  Positive           YES
1   NYC  01/06/1991      M  Negative            NO
2   LA   12/01/1980      F  Negative           YES
3   BOS  11/11/1987      M  Positive            NO
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the DFs are in a different order - I think it will not be possible to use this approach. But thank you anyways.